# Python - Make Script to Manipulate Windows File Paths but running on Linux

Tags: python, windows, linux, filesystems

I have this script which processes lines containing windows file paths.  However the script is running on Linux.  Is there a way to change the os library to do Windows file path handling while running on linux?

I was thinking something like:

```
import os
os.pathsep = '\\'
```

(which doesn't work since os.pathsep is ; for some reason)

My script:

```
for line in INPUT.splitlines():
    package_path,step_name = line.strip().split('>')
    file_name = os.path.basename(package_path)
    name = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]
    print template % (name,file_name,package_path)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the [ntpath](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module

On Linux, I did:

```
>> import ntpath      
>> ntpath.split("c:\windows\i\love\you.txt")
('c:\\windows\\i\\love', 'you.txt')
>> ntpath.splitext("c:\windows\i\love\you.txt")
('c:\\windows\\i\\love\\you', '.txt')
>> ntpath.basename("c:\windows\i\love\you.txt")
'you.txt'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `os.sep = '\\'`. os.pathsep is the separator used to separate the search path (PATH environment variable) on the os.

see [os module description](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html)

Answer (score 1):

os.pathsep is the separator that is used for the PATH environment variable.  You're looking for os.sep.

While I would generally advise against changing data in a module like that, it may suit your needs.  Alternatively, you could implement basename yourself, something like `package_path.split('\\')[-1]`